# generating .R file from .Rd file

Tags: r, roxygen2, rd

I know `roxygen2::roxygenise()` or `devtools::document()` cane be used to generate **.Rd** file from **.R** file.

For example, if **Test.R** is as follow

```
#' Add together two numbers
#'
#' @param x A number
#' @param y A number
#' @return The sum of \code{x} and \code{y}
#' @examples
#' add(1, 1)
#' add(10, 1)
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

Then the output of  `roxygen2::roxygenise()` or `devtools::document()` will be

```
% Generated by roxygen2 (3.2.0): do not edit by hand
\name{add}
\alias{add}
\title{Add together two numbers}
\usage{
add(x, y)
}
\arguments{
  \item{x}{A number}

  \item{y}{A number}
}
\value{
The sum of \code{x} and \code{y}
}
\description{
Add together two numbers
}
\examples{
add(1, 1)
add(10, 1)
}
```

However, I'm interested in vice versa. I do have **.Rd** which I want to convert into **.R** files. Any thoughts!

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker for pointing Rd2 roxygen R package. Would appreciate if you change your comment to answer for other users. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rd2roxygen` package will do this for you:

> It can parse an Rd file to a list, create the 'roxygen' documentation and update the original R script (e.g. the one containing the definition of the function) accordingly.

It's [on CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Rd2roxygen); the author's documentation page is [here](https://yihui.name/rd2roxygen/).

To convert a single Rd file you'd run

```
library(Rd2roxygen)
create_roxygen(parse_file("my_rd_file.Rd"))
```

which would return the results as a character vector (`writeLines()` to save it to a file).